# zgrep File to get Lines containing any of a list of words

Tags: grep, gzip

I have a large gzipped file and would like to get all the lines that contain any of a list of words. Is there a fast and efficient one line command to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try piped inclusions

```
zgrep -E "one|two|three" myfile.gz
```